# Hide text, but have it show up if copied and pasted without javascript

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a design for a short story site.
One of the stories I've been told would work better if someone copied and pasted text, extra lines would show up.

Is there anyway to achieve this with just HTML and CSS? I've tried using `display: none;` but that doesn't seem to copy the hidden text.  I do not want to use Javascript for this

Example HTML

`<div>Lorem ipsum <span class="inv">  ---- This is the cleverly hidden text ----  </span>dolor sit amet</div>`

The closest I've come is

```
width: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
height: 1em;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
```

If I do `width: 0;` it doesn't copy. The way above still shifts the text a small amount, and when highlighted, does show a bit of an artifact.

> (Unrelated to the question itself: But from what I understand, the intent is the story will strongly hint that when copied, hidden information shows up, which would lead to another unlisted story on the site for people who understand what its hinting at)

Comment: Without any provided code, I have no real idea what you mean

Comment: It sounds like you're suggesting to allow copying/pasting as a solution to a puzzle? eg, a phone game says to "Look at the solution from a new angle" and the solution is to rotate the phone; then similarly, trying to copy/paste certain text in a page would show more than was initially visible. There are multiple ways you could do this, but you could start by showing an example paragraph of HTML, with tags seperating the parts you'd like to work individually.

Comment: Depending on what you want, you could simply give it a matching colour to the background, or an RGBA colour with full opacity. I believe both of those should still allow selection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a possible solution to this problem, however it may or may not be appropriate.

**Only appears after pasting**

Potentially if you want it to only appear in the pasted text (rather than when it's highlighted) you could make the font take up no space, so it can be hidden between the other text e.g.

```css
div {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.hidden{
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is visible. 
  <span class="hidden">This is not.</span>
  (Copy and paste this to see the hidden line)
</div>
```

**Visible while selected**

If you would prefer the text to be visible simply by selecting it, you can either match the background colour set it to a transparent colour.

```css
div {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.hidden1{
  /* Match the background colour */
  color: #FFF;
}

.hidden2{
  /* Transparent text, should work on any background colour */
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is visible. 
  <span class="hidden1">This is not.</span>
  <span class="hidden2">Nor is this.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That shifts the text ever so slighty.  Is there any reason not to use font-size: 0?  That + the color to rgba with 0 alpha seems to be working.

Comment: @Trel I was a little worried `font-size: 0` may cause issues with certain browsers, however I think it's probably safe. Edit: Had a quick google around, and it seems safe to use.

Comment: If it's safe to use, then `font-size: 0; color: rgba(255,255,255,0);` is the perfect answer.

Comment: @DBS Why do you need transparent color? The `0` font size hides the element entirely, so there's nothing visible in the default color anyway. Right? Also, I tried `opacity: 0;` as an alternative to transparent color. Seems to work. But I think neither transparent color nor opacity setting is necessary. Just font size setting alone is sufficient.

Comment: @ADTC The transparency was mostly a just-in-case, I wasn't sure if `0px` fonts would cause issues in some of the browsers we still had to support in 2016. It certainly shouldn't be necessary anymore (if it ever was) I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just a demonstration of the solution discussed in the comments of DBS' answer. Selecting the text will not indicate to you that you've selected any more than "This is visible", but pasting it into Notepad will show everything. Seems perfect for small ARGs or internet-based puzzles.

```css
div {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.hidden1{
  /* Match the background colour */
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 0;
}

.hidden2{
  /* Transparent text, should work on any background colour */
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is visible. 
  <span class="hidden1">This is not.</span>
  <span class="hidden2">Nor is this.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What is an ARG?

Comment: @SOFe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_reality_game

Comment: with `font-size:0` any other styles are irrelevant.