# Hide text between words, but show it when copy/pasted

Tags: javascript, css

HTML:

```
<p>This is <span>blah blah</span>my sentence.</p>
```

When you see it in the browser, it should show:

> This is my sentence.

When you drag/select the sentence in the HTML then copy/paste it elsewhere, it should say:

> This is blah blahmy sentence.

When CSS property do I need to apply to `span` so that it behaves like this? `display:none` will hide it, but it doesn't show `blah blah` when copy/pasted.

Comment: This was already explored here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926864/hide-text-but-have-it-show-up-if-copied-and-pasted-without-javascript